# Prawn pdf bounding_box not working over the span of multiple pages

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I have a custom method that takes a string and a block and is supposed to display whatever the block passed calls, inside a rectangle with rounded borders. This works perfectly fine when the content is small enough to fit the remaining page, but when it's not the borders only display on the second page, they're longer than they should be and the title seems to disappear

This is how it should look

[image: Good]

This is how it looks with a lot of content (in this case text) that spans over two pages:

Page 1:

[image: Bad - Page 1]

Page 2:

[image: Bad - Page 2]

```
def get_size_of_text str, opts
      ret = [0, 0]
      font(opts[:fontName], style: opts[:fontStyle], size: opts[:fontSize]) do
          ret = [
              height_of_typeset_text(str),
              rendered_width_of_string(str)
          ]
      end
      ret
  end

def customBox title, &block
      title_height, title_width = get_size_of_text title, fontName: "M+ 1mn", fontStyle: :bold, fontSize: 20

      title_width += 30
      title_height += 5

      stroke do
          fill_color '000000'
          fill_and_stroke_rounded_rectangle [(page_usable_width - title_width) * 0.5, cursor + 5], title_width, title_height, 10
          fill_color '000000'
      end

      box = bounding_box [0, cursor], width: page_usable_width do
          move_down title_height
          bounding_box [10, cursor], width: page_usable_width - 20 do
              block.call
          end
      end

      stroke do
          stroke_color '000000'
          line_width 2.5
          stroke_rounded_rectangle [0, cursor + box.update_height - 10], page_usable_width, box.update_height - 20, 10
      end

      move_up box.update_height

      font("M+ 1mn", :style => :bold, size: 20, align: :center) do
          stroke_color "ffffff"
          fill_color "ffffff"
          text title, align: :center
      end

      move_down box.update_height - 20
  end
```

Comment: Please also include your code.

Comment: @arjun oh... of course, I don't know how i forgot to include the most important part, the code lol

Comment: Out of curiosity did you try playing around with the font size/family?  After how many lines or characters does the error start to exhibit (under your current settings)?

Comment: @tukan the font size & family is unrelated, the problem starts happening once the box reaches the end of the page, which can be 3 lines or 30 depending on the box's position on the page.

Comment: I see.  Well did you try to create two boxes?  One would be the title with the left/right rounds and the rest would be another box containing only the edges and bottom? (via layout)